# Batch file to run PowerShell Script Only Works Once

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So I'm trying to create a batch file to run a PowerShell script while bypassing the execution policy.  Oddly, it worked a single time, but without me editing anything, it will not run again.  I've created other files thinking maybe my file somehow got corrupted, but nothing...  Any chance someone sees anything blatantly wrong with this?

```
@echo off
Powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0File.ps1' -Verb RunAs}"
PAUSE
```

The *.ps1 file works by itself if I click through the prompts.  Also, if I manually set the execution policy in PowerShell to Bypass, this batch file still does not work.  This is not a process I usually need to take, so I'm curious if anyone sees anything wrong with how this is written?

Comment: Is it getting stuck on the pause without user input?

Comment: Your example seems to work for me.

Comment: I'm not seeing the pause at all.  I see a CMD window pop up for a moment, a PowerShell window pop up for a moment, and then they both vanish with seemingly nothing happening.  But the  pause is after the PowerShell line, so shouldn't it pause after that runs?

Comment: Wow ... that's new. ;-)  ... you're using one command line interface to start another command line interface to start the second command line interface again.   ;-)  You could simply use a link with the command line you need. Like `Powershell -ep bypass -file 'Your Powershell script'`  ... and you cannot bypass the Execution Policy for scripts from inside a script. ;-)

Comment: `PAUSE` will occur after the `powershell` command, but if that starts a process in a new window, and that process ends, then you'll see the window appear, disappear, and then the "Press Enter to continue... :" prompt.

Comment: @Olaf got me in the right place, thanks.  My bigger issue was that I'm also having to call another PowerShell script from within my PowerShell script...  So my bat file now gathers the current execution policy, dumps that into a temporary txt file, then runs a command to change the entire system to bypass as opposed to just one script, runs all the scripts I need to run, then finally uses the txt file I created at the beginning to create another script to change the execution policy back to what it was before I started.  I'm certain there is a better way to do this, but this worked.

Comment: @ChristopherCass ... wow, that's even worse. It sounds like the tail's wagging the dog. ;-)  No offense ... I'd recommend that you try to get some help from a trained person. I'm pretty sure there must be a cleaner way to do whatever you do.

Comment: I'm certain there is, but there are no resources for me at the moment other than Google and I'm in a time crunch.  It worked, so maybe in the future I'll be able to clean it up, but it does what I need for now.

Answer (score 2):

If this is just to run your script, what I personally do is create a shortcut of the script and then modify the `Target` of the shortcut:

Target: `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\scriptpath\script.ps1"`

If you want your script to be executed as **Administrator** you can add this to the top of the main script:

```
$myInvoke="-file `"$($MyInvocation.ScriptName)`""
Start-Process "$PSHome\powershell.exe" -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $myInvoke -EA 'Stop'
```

If the shortcut will always be in the same folder as your script you can also leave `Start In` blank and change the path for `Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\script.ps1"` by doing so if you copy the entire folder to a different location, the shortcut will still work.